# Laravel 10 Docker Installation using Sail

Tags: docker, ubuntu, curl, laravel-10, laravel-sail

I am in Windows 11 with wsl and I'm trying to install a fresh laravel 10 project with Docker using Sail. I ran the command `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` in terminal but gave me this error message.

> failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils librsvg2-bin fswatch     && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.2-cli php8.2-dev        php8.2-pgsql php8.2-sqlite3 php8.2-gd php8.2-imagick        php8.2-curl        php8.2-imap php8.2-mysql php8.2-mbstring        php8.2-xml php8.2-zip php8.2-bcmath php8.2-soap        php8.2-intl php8.2-readline        php8.2-ldap        php8.2-msgpack php8.2-igbinary php8.2-redis php8.2-swoole        php8.2-memcached php8.2-pcov php8.2-xdebug     && curl -sLS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_VERSION.x nodistro main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && npm install -g pnpm     && npm install -g bun     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

Can someone help me please?

Comment: It can be any of these lines. Copy that .sh file to your local wsl2. Then edit that msh file. Focus on those .gpg key lines. Split that 'command' in multiple commands right after those lines with .gpg in them. chmod +x that local .sh file and then run that file. You have to pinpoint the error